# Dynamic class level type hints in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plugins, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm trying to provide type hinting in PyCharm dynamically for a specific class, meaning that one of its attributes has assigned a value during `__init__`, which on its turn is an object.

I've tried defining a class level type for the attribute, however the type of the attribute could be one of multiple classes, so I can't really point towards a specific type, but I would want to be able to have auto-complete on that attribute.

```
class Dynamic:
    def __init__(self):
        self.field1 = "field1"
        self.field2 = "field2"


class Reusable:
    def __init__(self, dynamics=None):
        if dynamics:
            self.values = dynamics
        else:
            self.values = "nothing"


dynamic_test = Dynamic()
test = Reusable(dynamics=dynamic_test)
print(test.values.)  # this is the place where auto-complete should take place
```

Obviously, the auto-complete does not take place. 
I tried things similar to

```
class Reusable:
    value_type = str  # type to-be-modified later
    values: value_type

    def __init__(self, dynamics=None):
        if dynamics:
            self.values = dynamics
        else:
            self.values = "nothing"
        Reusable.value_type = type(self.values)  # doesn't actually modify that so I won't have auto-complete based on type
```

I know that there's some possibilities involving handling the builtin `__dir__` function, however I haven't gotten any luck with that either (not sure if dependent on PyCharm's auto-complete algorithm or not), nor any plugins have been developed in this direction.

Is there any way I can go around this one and have that auto-complete feature in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using type hints:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T")


class Reusable(Generic[T]):
    values: Union[str, T]

    def __init__(self, dynamics: T = None):
        if dynamics:
            self.values = dynamics
        else:
            self.values = "nothing"
```

Here we marked `Reusable` as a class that could be parameterized with `T`.

By marking `dynamics` as `T` we are specified where to get exact value of `T`.

`Union[str, T]` means that `values` is either `str` or `T`.

See [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for more details.